# Objectify projection queries returning null

Tags: android, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I can't seem to get my projection query to return anything but null, not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Here's the code where I set up and call the query:

```
    Query query1 = OfyService.ofy().load().type(CargoEntity.class).
       project("imageUrl", "latitude", "longitude").distinct(false); //filter("group", group);

    // Execute the query:
    List<Entity> results = query1.list();

    logger.warning("(Query from datastore results.isEmpty()) : " + (results.isEmpty()));
    logger.warning("(Group = ) : " + group);

    if (!results.isEmpty()) {
        logger.warning("(Query from datastore results.size()) : " + (results.size()));
        //Create STRTree-Index.
        STRtree strTree = new STRtree();
        GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();

        //Loop through the  result list from DataStore.
        for (Entity result : results) {

            STRLeaf leaf = new STRLeaf((float)result.getProperty("latitude"), (float)result.getProperty("longitude"), (String)result.getProperty("imageUrl"));

            Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(leaf.getLongitude(), leaf.getLatitude());

            Point point = gf.createPoint(coord);

            //Add result to index.
            strTree.insert(point.getEnvelopeInternal(), leaf);
        }
```

I'm really new to this so it could be something obvious that i'm missing.  I do see the indexes in the developers console though.  Here's what the properties in my Entity looks like:

```
@Entity
@Index
@Cache
public class CargoEntity {

//datastore key
@Id
private String imageUrl;
private float latitude;
private float longitude;
private String group;
@Unindex
private int rating;
@Unindex
private Blob image;
@Unindex
private String email;
@Unindex
private String userName;
@Unindex
private String description;
@Unindex
private Date date;
@Unindex
private String blobKey;
@Unindex
private String type;
@Unindex
private boolean flag;
@Unindex
private int photoOrientation;

public CargoEntity() {
}
//getters and setters below
```

Comment: Do you have a multiproperty index defined for those three fields?

Comment: In developers console under datastore - indexes I see Indexes

CargoEntity group ▲ + imageUrl ▲ + latitude ▲ + longitude ▲----
imageUrl ▲ + latitude ▲ + longitude ▲ ----
state ▲ + imageUrl ▲ + latitude ▲ + longitude ▲----

Comment: I added a new multiproperty index into the datastore and ran this filtered query which returned a non null result.  Query query1 = OfyService.ofy().load().type(CargoEntity.class).filter("group", group).filter("latitude >", 0.0);   This works and so I think the problem is in the projection query call.  I looked for other examples of people using a projection query with Objectify but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Here are the test cases. If you can add one that breaks, submit a PR: https://github.com/objectify/objectify/blob/master/src/test/java/com/googlecode/objectify/test/QueryProjectionTests.java

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google App Engine projection query returns 0 results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760437/google-app-engine-projection-query-returns-0-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently I was adding the Entity id to the projection query which is not allowed (or it is allowed but returns null).  This post answered the problem.

[Google App Engine projection query returns 0 results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760437/google-app-engine-projection-query-returns-0-results)